# Android: rotate canvas around the center of the screen

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-canvas

I'm trying to rotate the canvas around the center of the screen, to get the (0,0) coordinates at the bottom right.

This is how I do it:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
canvas.rotate(180, width/2, height/2);
```

It does rotate correctly, and everything is perfect at the AVD with API level 17. But on the AVD with API level 8 the (0,0) coordinate appears at the wrong place. Before rotation the picture was fitting the whole screen at this device too, but now it looks like this:

[image]

what is causing the problem?

*EDIT!

The problem is resolved by rotating the canvas around its own middle point:

```
canvas.rotate(180,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2);
```

But still, why doesn't the previous version work with older APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not always necessary for the `Canvas` and the `Display` to have the same size. `Display.getWidth()` is deprecated and it is suggested to use `Display.getSize()` instead. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)):

> Gets the size of the display, in pixels.
>
> Note that this value should not be used for computing layouts, since a
>   device will typically have screen decoration (such as a status bar)
>   along the edges of the display that reduce the amount of application
>   space available from the size returned here. Layouts should instead
>   use the window size.

So, in case of `canvas` matrix transformation, always use the `canvas` as reference rather than the Display or Window, because the canvas would give the accurate value. So to rotate the canvas around the center, you need the center of the `canvas`.

The center of the canvas is `(canvas.getWidth()/2 , canvas.getHeight()/2)`